# Cannot get DHCP lease through wireless-to-wired bridge

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, ethernet, bridge

I am trying to bridge wlan0 and eth0 on a embedded board. That board is going to be
connected to my home AP via wifi and I expect to connect my laptop to the wired
leg of the bridge and have access to my home LAN and internet.
The whole set up looks like this:

---

- laptop -> eth0 -> embedded board (Khadas VIM3L) with bridge -> wlan0 -> LAN *

---

So far I've been able to successfully set a bridge between the wlan0 and eth0
interfaces of the embedded board with the following commands:

```bash
# WIFI Connection on the khadas board
sudo nmcli device wifi connect ${MY-AP-SSID} password ${MY-AP-PASSWORD}

# Setting up the bridge on the khadas board
sudo iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on
sudo ip link set dev wlan0 up;
sudo ip link set dev eth0 up;
sudo ip addr flush wlan0;
sudo ip addr flush eth0;
sudo ip link add name br0 type bridge nf_call_iptables 0;
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0;
sudo brctl addif br0 wlan0;
sudo brctl stp br0 on;
sudo ip link set dev br0 up;

sudo dhclient -v br0;
```

The bridge on the embedded board seems to be up and running:

```bash
khadas@Khadas:~$ sudo brctl show
bridge name bridge id             STP enabled   interfaces
br0           8000.70f754e4b567 yes           eth0
                                                        wlan0

khadas@Khadas:~$ sudo ip addr
...
10: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:f7:54:e4:b5:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.248/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 14194sec preferred_lft 14194sec
    inet6 2001:1308:2830:6b00:85a1:a05c:6bf9:a94d/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86165sec preferred_lft 86117sec
    inet6 2001:1308:2830:6b00:72f7:54ff:fee4:b567/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 86165sec preferred_lft 86165sec
    inet6 fe80::72f7:54ff:fee4:b567/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Despite the bridge apparently working, I cannot get an IP lease for my laptop connected to the board
through ethernet.

From my laptop's perspective:

```bash
❯ sudo dhclient -v enp0s31f6
[sudo] password for gabriel:
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.3
Copyright 2004-2022 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s31f6/6c:24:08:a9:86:8c
Sending on   LPF/enp0s31f6/6c:24:08:a9:86:8c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
xid: warning: no netdev with useable HWADDR found for seed's uniqueness enforcement
xid: rand init seed (0x6435e938) built using gethostid
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x39f0361d)
...
```

From the embedded board with the bridge perspective:

```bash
khadas@Khadas:~$ sudo tcpdump -i br0 -vv -n -e  port 67 or port 68
tcpdump: listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
17:25:13.340635 6c:24:08:a9:86:8c > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 6c:24:08:a9:86:8c, length 300, xid 0x39f0361d, Flags [none] (0x0000)
      Client-Ethernet-Address 6c:24:08:a9:86:8c
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
        Requested-IP Option 50, length 4: 10.0.0.88
        Hostname Option 12, length 12: "ThinkPad-E15"
        Parameter-Request Option 55, length 13: 
          Subnet-Mask, BR, Time-Zone, Default-Gateway
          Domain-Name, Domain-Name-Server, Option 119, Hostname
          Netbios-Name-Server, Netbios-Scope, MTU, Classless-Static-Route
          NTP
...
```

The DHCP requests are reaching to the bridge, but apparently are not being forwarded to my home AP.

Any ideas of what could be the issue?

Comment: Two things to consider 1/ you must allow on the AP the use of 4addr from the STA (the client). The associated vocabulary could be WDS. For example if the AP is a Linux running hostapd, the hostapd.conf configuration option is `wds_sta=1`. 2/ changing the setup in the back of NetworkManager might confuse it or might make fail reauthentication after it's done. You probably need a manual setup using your own wpa_supplicant.conf . The important part is 1/ : the AP, ie not done on the board. A standard cheap home AP probably doesn't allow such setup.

Comment: I'm waiting for any feedback from you in case some clarification is needed. I also need some clarification: why? If that's to get any Ethernet-only device able to use Wireless with the use of a helper "box", as you see that's not that simple. There are even other ways that don't depend on 4addr mode but have (of course) other limitations.

Comment: @A.B I was looking in the settings of the web GUI of my home AP and apparently the
4addr mode is nowhere to be seen, I would need to connect to it via telnet or
SSH and see if I can do the appropriate configurations there. 
The bad news is that apparently the telnet and SSH credentials of my AP are
something I should ask my ISP, so I'll have to call them tomorrow Monday.

What I want to do is basically get a Ethernet-only device be able to connect to my home wlan transparently.
Is there a way to achieve that without the Ethernet-Wifi bridge?

Comment: [parprouted](https://manpages.debian.org/parprouted/parprouted.8) + [DHCP relay](https://manpages.debian.org/isc-dhcp-relay/dhcrelay.8) allows to make a router mimicing a bridge. drawback among others: no broadcast (hence the need of a DHCP relay to work around what's needed for normal DHCP). Now to have this auto-configure itself whatever its network is the real challenge.

Comment: @A.B, this should be enough - right?
```bash
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp
parprouted eth0 wlan0
dhcrelay 10.0.0.1 -i eth0 -i wlan0
```
According to [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/bridge-wi-fi-to-wired-ethernet-4175596353/#post5650091) it should be enough, but for some reason dhclient on my laptop does not get the lease.